# jquery Popup that displays and then goes away?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just a link and it has a popup

1.show link(pause 3 seconds)

2.Activate the Popup

3.Pause for 4 seconds & remove Popup

4.Loop at 1

How can i do it with jquery?

Can i do with setTimeout() function or setInterval() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout("alert(\"pop up\");", 4000);
```

That should do it

Comment: eval()'s are evil.  Try `setTimeout(function () { alert("pop up"); }, 4000)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use jQuery BlockUI - http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
 }, 4000);
```

then do handy code to setTimeout for show link. good luck.